# wait for API call or subscription to finish/return before calling other subscriptions (await)

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, rxjs

I am getting a bunch of failed API calls in the network tab in chrome. This is because I can see on the waterfall that my "create customer" subscription hasn't finished its execution yet, then "create address" and "create contact phone number" both run and don't wait for it to finish.

I have looked for answers using the await....toPromise() function, but that is now deprecated and doesn't work in my scenario.

How would I implement this in newer versions of rxjs/angular?

```
// API call for create customer
this.userService.createCustomer(customer).subscribe({
  next: (customerResult: Customer) => {
    const createContactAddress =
      customerAddress !== undefined
        ? this.userService.createContactAddress(
            customerResult.partyNumber,
            customerAddress.toJson()
          )
        : of(undefined);
    const createContactEmail =
      email !== undefined
        ? this.userService.createContactPhoneEmail(
            customerResult.partyNumber,
            email
          )
        : of(undefined);
    const createContactPhoneNumber =
      phone !== undefined
        ? this.userService.createContactPhoneEmail(
            customerResult.partyNumber,
            phone
          )
        : of(undefined);

    createContactAddress
      .pipe(combineLatestWith(createContactEmail, createContactPhoneNumber))
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.modalSaved.emit(customerResult);
        },
        error: () => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.closeModal();
        }
      });
  },
  error: () => {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.closeModal();
  }
});
```

}

Comment: what I understood ,you want to perform these three `createContactAddress`,`createContactEmail`,`createContactPhoneNumber` after completion of `createCustomer` and want to complete the stream after finish all.Did I get you correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switchMap/mergeMap` to execute the logic in `subscribe` instead of nested subscribe

```
// API call for create customer
this.userService
  .createCustomer(customer)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((customerResult: Customer) => {
      const createContactAddress =
        customerAddress !== undefined
          ? this.userService.createContactAddress(
              customerResult.partyNumber,
              customerAddress.toJson()
            )
          : of(undefined);
      const createContactEmail =
        email !== undefined
          ? this.userService.createContactPhoneEmail(
              customerResult.partyNumber,
              email
            )
          : of(undefined);
      const createContactPhoneNumber =
        phone !== undefined
          ? this.userService.createContactPhoneEmail(
              customerResult.partyNumber,
              phone
            )
          : of(undefined);

      return createContactAddress.pipe(
        combineLatestWith(createContactEmail, createContactPhoneNumber)
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: () => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.modalSaved.emit(customerResult);
    },
    error: () => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.closeModal();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

> **What I understood is**,
>
> 1. you want to call `this.userService.createCustomer`
> 2. After completion of **[1]** you want to perform these three `createContactAddress`, `createContactEmail`,
>    `createContactPhoneNumber`
> 3. After completion of [1] and [2] you want to complete the stream.

On basis of my understanding I am providing my solution

```ts
this.userService
  .createCustomer(customer)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((customerResult: Customer) =>
      forkJoin([
        this.createContactAddress(customerAddress, customerResult),
        this.createContactEmail(email, customerResult),
        this.createContactPhoneNumber(phone, customerResult),
      ]).pipe(map((result) => [customerResult, ...result]))
    ),
    catchError((err) => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.closeModal();
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (customerResult, addressResult, emailResult, phoneResult) => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.modalSaved.emit(customerResult);
    },
    error: () => {
      this.isSaving = false;
      this.closeModal();
    },
  });


createContactAddress(customerAddress, customerResult): Observable<any> {
  return customerAddress !== undefined
    ? this.userService.createContactAddress(
        customerResult.partyNumber,
        customerAddress.toJson()
      )
    : of(undefined);
}

createContactEmail(email, customerResult): Observable<any> {
  return email !== undefined
    ? this.userService.createContactPhoneEmail(
        customerResult.partyNumber,
        email
      )
    : of(undefined);
}

createContactPhoneNumber(phone, customerResult): Observable<any> {
  return phone !== undefined
    ? this.userService.createContactPhoneEmail(
        customerResult.partyNumber,
        phone
      )
    : of(undefined);
}
```